# I can not change the function name in .js file. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem after changing the name of a function inside a .js file. I do not know what I am doing wrong?

index.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="env" name="env" onchange="loadClusters()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Environment </option>
```

exec.js

```
function loadClusters() {
  window.location.href = "/execution?env=" + $('#env').val() + '&type=' + $('#type').val();
}
```

When I change the name of the function to `loadCluster`, for example, it is not working.

Comment: Did you change the function name in both `exec.js` and `index.html`?

Comment: Why does it not work? I would assume that you have missed renaming the function in a location it's called from. Check the console for errors

Comment: Hit the F12 button on your browser and see if you see any (x) in RED... copy paste that here :D

Comment: Rebuild the project after you change the function and/ or html.

Comment: Doesn't answer why it does not work, which you have not provided the example that does not work, but if you used logical bindings instead of inline binding, the name of the function becomes pointless.

Comment: Maybe you have a something else that is also called `loadCluster` already defined somewhere else?

Comment: execution:134 Uncaught ReferenceError: loadCluster is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (execution:134)

Comment: I am changing the name in both exec.js and index.html

Comment: sometimes there is something in js where you return functions at the end. Are you sure you replaced all occurence of the old function name?

Comment: Finally, It is SOLVED. I tried on firefox it worked. After that, I cleaned the Chrome cache and worked fine. Thanks, for the help :)

Comment: It's not very helpfull to write solved in the title. Rather write an answer sn sccept it or delete the question. Like this it will still pop up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clear The Cached browser data. If you are using chrome:

#### *Settings --> More tools --> Clear browsing data --> Cached images and files*

2. Invalidate the cached data in your IDE.
3. Disable Caching your Chrome browser:

#### *Settings --> More tools --> Developer tools --> Network --> Disable Cache.*

Answer (score 0):

Plz note that when you import the function from exec.js, the function's name(i.e the name of function being imported) should start with a capital letter.